# combine sprintf with IF condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm stuck with a stupid problem. I was asked to arrange some changes in a php website template. So here is the code for the header/hyperlink:

```
<?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
```

And this should be combined with:

```
<?php if( in_category('local-msr') ) { echo 'target="_blank" '; } ?>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
<?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark" if( in_category('local-msr') ), echo 'target="_blank">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
```

But without succes.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a third parameter to `sprintf`.

You could do it all on one line, but for clarity I will write it out:

```
// set a variable that has the target or is empty if the condition is not met
$target = in_category('local-msr') ? 'target="_blank"' : '';
the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" %s rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ), $target ), '</a></h1>' );
//                                                        ^^ add the variable here
//                                                                                                         ^^^^^^^ the value
```